# Bootstrap modal and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I am using [AngularStrap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##modals) in my application. I am tying to implement the [modal](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##modals) feature of bootstrap. The problem is that I can't make it to show up my `template` modal. [**Here is a link to plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/rcIA7J3fPMno2as6tXDm?p=preview). My template's id is `test` and I am referring in (like explained in the docs) by `template='#test'` but I am getting an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs state the following for `template`:

> If provided, overrides the default template, can be either a remote URL or a cached template id.

In angular a template can either be loaded from a remote source or defined directly in a script tag. All templates are loaded via an instance of [`$templateCache`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24templateCache). So, to make your modal show you need to change the definition of your modal to look like:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="test">
    <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header" ng-show="title">
                    <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="$hide()">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" ng-bind="title"></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" ng-bind="content"></div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$hide()">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AIvMtKyaU0lp376qc1YD) to demonstrate.

Comment: Looks like it follows the same principle - create a `script` element with an identifier and reference that from the `content-template` of your modal. Updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AIvMtKyaU0lp376qc1YD)